# 'laravel8 + vue3 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component')'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-8

***'laravel8 + vue3***
**error** `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component')`

how can this error be avoided ?

**app.js**

```
window.Vue = require('vue').default;
Vue.component('hello', require('./hello.vue').default);
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<body class="antialiased">
    <div class="relative flex items-top justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 sm:items-center py-4 sm:pt-0">
        <div id="app">
            <hello></hello>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>
</body>
```

**hello.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hello World!
    </div>
</template>
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.11",
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "vue": "^3.2.11",
    "vue-loader": "^16.5.0"
}
```

this error appears in vue3

tell me how to avoid it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in `Vue3` Your `app.js` should be like that:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import hello from './components/hello.vue';

let app=createApp({})
app.component('hello' , hello);

app.mount("#app")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Vue2 setup. Change it to vue3 as above mentioned.